# Redirection of error page does not work

Tags: java, jsf, custom-error-pages

I want to create a custom error page within my java webapp.
Like the most of the posts suggest I added a rule in my web.xml

```
`    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/error-pages/standard-error.xhtml</location>
     </error-page>
```

`

In the Error-Page I want to show a Mail-Adress to contact the sysadmin:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewAction action="#{settingsManagedBean.onLoad}" />
</f:metadata>
.....
Please contact:
Mail: #{settingsManagedBean.editSet.systemmail}
```

The problem is that when an error occurs the page doesn't get redirected and just renders the error page. The bad thing is that it does not load the managed bean for the mail address.

[image]

When I open the page manually with the right link the page gets shown including the Mailaddress:

[image]

What did I miss? I would appreciate help a lot :-)

Comment: your page not processed by the faces servlet. check the path of the error page. is it inside the domain of the faces servlet of your web app?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I`m very new to jsf. How can i evaluate if the side is inside the domain? ... Sorry for the noob-question ;-) Got no answer through google :-/

Comment: check the settings in web.xml. what is the faces servlet path? does the path of your page match in it?

Comment: Here are the settings in my web.xml. Not included are filter, bootstrap, and error-page settings   `<servlet>
 <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
 <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/sefb.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`

Comment: add this after the `<servlet>` element : `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping><session-config><session-timeout>30</session-timeout></session-config><welcome-file-list><welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this i changed the error.xhtml site to a .jsp site. It gets rendered without a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, you must configure the url-pattern to FacesServlet, and put the file extensions necessary. For example, i use error pages from other framework that have the .xhtml extension, for this reason, I have to add it to my configuration. With these the problem was solved.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.mat</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```